# Show custom product field in new order email

Tags: woocommerce

i created a custom field in a product called **course-date**. I asissnged it a date e.g Jan 30. This is what I have in the email yet nothing shows.. am i missing something? code edited with new snippet below

[image]

```
    <?php
/**
 * Customer processing order email
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     2.4.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
    $course_date=get_post_meta($product_id, 'course-date', true);
    //Note $course_date will get overwritten if there are more than one items in the order.
}
?>

<?php do_action('woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading); ?>

<p>This email is to notify you of your recent registration for the <b>Level 1 - Think and Grow Rich Institute Course</b>!</p>

<p>You are registered to attend on:</p>

<p><?php printf( __( '<b>Registration ID:</b> %s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></p>
<p><b>Course Registration Date:</b> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->id, 'course-date', true); ?></p>
<p><b>Time:</b> 8am Registration - 9am Event Begins (<a href="http://allfansnomoney.com/thinkandgrowrich/tentative-schedule/" target="_blank">See Full Schedule</a>)</p>
<p><b>Location:</b> 240 Belfield Rd, Toronto, ON M9W 1H3</p>

<p>If you have any questions please contact us by e-mail: <a href="mailto:contact@thinkandgrowrichinstitute.com">contact@thinkandgrowrichinstitute.com</a>.</p>

<p>Sincerely,<BR/>
The Think and Grow Rich Institute Team</p><BR/>

<p><em><b>"Whatever The Mind Can Conceive and Believe, It Will Achieve."</b> - Napoleon Hill</em></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer' ); ?>
```

Comment: How are you defining `$_product`? How are you adding this code to the email? Where? Please edit your question with the extra info.

Comment: I have edited and included the full email template. By defining $_product, I am assuming I have to add a snippet or something to functions.php? Sorry still learning

Comment: Is it possible I can hire you to get this done for me? I can't figure it out and I need it done asap, please let me know.

Comment: Based on the subject of the new content you are adding, I would probably suggest [creating a new email](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/) that only sends the information about the course when that item is purchased. [Follow up Emails](https://www.woothemes.com/products/follow-up-emails/) might be very appropriate here. Or [WooCommerce Bookings](https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/) for a full-blown booking system.

Answer (score 3):

Hope you get to learn more from this answer and it adds to you knowledge of WooCommerce.

For the Snippet you sent of the "Customer processing order email".

The system is unable to find the value of $_product->id here. So it is not working.

You have to debug it by print the Product id itself in the initial test emails.

If you are unable to get the product id. Here is a bit more information.

An order may have more than one products. So finding the product with the meta fields can be troublesome especially when you are having a question of which product you should show the meta field of.

Easy way is to use the given object $order retrieve the order id from this  object then find all the products associated in this order and then find meta field value for those products.

```
<?php
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
    $course_date=get_post_meta($product_id, 'course-date', true);
    if(isset($course_date) && $course_date!=""){
      echo "<p><b>Course Registration Date:</b>".$course_date."</p>";
   }
}
?>
```

Let us know whether this gave you any insight of the issue.

Comment: That makes sense, however I have no clue where I'm adding this? I tried adding it to template is seperate php tags but it still didn't work.. I modified my code above.. let me know if I am heading in the right direction pls? Thank you

Comment: Hi, Have modified the code. Now you can just place the code in "Customer processing order email" wherever you wish to display the line in the email.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an untested example of how to add a string to the "customer_processing_email" without overriding the template. You would add this code to your theme's `functions.php` and the text should appear prior to the order table.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'kia_custom_order_details', 5, 4 );
function kia_custom_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){

    if( $email->id == "customer_processing_order" ){

        $course_date = null;

        // borrowing the loop from WisdmLabs's answer
        $items = $order->get_items();

        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_name = $item['name'];
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
            $course_date = get_post_meta($product_id, 'course-date', true);
            if( $course_date != '' ) break; //break out of the loop if we find a course date
        }

        if( $course_date && $plain_text ){

            echo "Course Registration Date: " . $course_date . "\n\n";

        } else if( $course_date && ! $plain_text ){

            echo "<p><b>Course Registration Date:</b> " . $course_date . "</p>" . "/n/n";

        }

    }
}
```

Don't forget the different formatting for rich text versus plain text emails. I left most of the formatting for the rest of your text to you as the important part was finding/printing the course date meta.

I still think that using a separate email would be the best approach here, but as far as I can tell you were only missing echoing out `$course_date` in the right place.